# PayPal MPL library's preapprovalWithKey method neither returns any error nor calls any delegate. How to handle?

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-mpl

I am using PayPal MPL in my project.
The server fetches me a key for preapproval and I open up the MPL UI for authorizing the key.

For opening the UI I call the following method:

```
[[PayPal getPayPalInst] preapprovalWithKey:payPalPreAprovalKey andMerchantName:@"<My App's Name>"];
```

Method definition:

```
-(void)preapprovalWithKey:(NSString *)preapprovalKey andMerchantName:(NSString *)merchantName;
```

Now the problem is sometimes when MPL is down neither does this method call return any error nor does it call any failure delegate so I practically don't have any way to find out if the MPL auth UI was opened or not and because of that my UI hangs because I add the view of the controller which is handling this process as a transparent subview and hence the UI seems to be hanged.

Am I missing out on any way to handle this?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: there were an issue discuss in the github (https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/issues/74) look at the last comments.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AnaheimElectronics. 
That issue also was posted by me. There the discussion is more about the resolution of the problem that MPL UI is not opening up but nothing related to handling the method callback or response.